# Handling how .Net Serializes Nullable types

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, nullable

By default, .Net ends up xml serializing nullable types into a node that looks similar to this

```
<SomeNode p3:nil="true" xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Unfortunately, given that the object model I am serializing has many many many null values, I end up with a very large xml document (185mb) when it should be much smaller with the null nodes removed completely (20mb)

The object definition is autogenerated when I add a webservice reference, so, thankfully it is declared as a partial class and I am able to create my own partial classes that add a bunch of `ShouldSerialize*` methods to prevent serializing any null values.

However, this is rather tedious, as the classes are large, and there are many of them.

Is there a way I can use reflection, to simplify the process of adding `ShouldSerialize*` methods to a class at runtime for all public properties?

Like I wrote, I did this manually for some of the classes, and it's highly repetitive, 100s of functions that all look like this

```
public bool ShouldSerializeNotes() { return Notes != null; }
```

Thanks,
-c

Comment: Are you sure you need to return 20mb of data from a *web service*? What's in the data? How many rows/objects/entitites?

Comment: Actually I'm pushing 20mb of data to a web service.  It's a 38000 line transaction.  It's rare that they will be this size...but 20mb we can deal with, 185mb is extreme

Comment: Not having done an extreme amount of web service programming, I've done my fair share of XML serialization, and one thing I use a lot is the `XYZSpecified` property convention, does that work with web services? Could that help?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, the `ShouldSerialize*` works, it's cut the size down...it's just tedious to setup because I have to create a bunch of partial classes and many nearly identical methods in each class by hand.  The Specified issue would be the same problem, I have to manually setup all the properties.  I'm trying to simplify this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Marc's idea, but a bit more streamlined, you could stick all the class and property names into a text or XML file, then use that as the input to a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) that generates the partial classes with the ShouldSerialize* methods. T4 seems to be completely undocumented in VS2008, but if you give a text file in your solution a .tt extension, it should set you up with the right Custom Tool for code generation. Everything is supported properly in VS2010.

Comment: ~50 line T4 template and a bit of reflection and I have this working.

Comment: Even more streamlined :) Great!

Answer (score 2):

As a 1-off you could just write the property names to a text file (via type.GetProperties()), and use basic tools (a spreadsheet would suffice) to generate a basic method be property. Not sophisticated, but pragmatic. Of course you'd need to account for ongoing changes.

To answer the question as posed; no, not really (unless you implement IXmlSerializable, which is a pain).

I would ask, though: does it have to be XML? I could make that much smaller *and* have the behaviour you describe (no data written for nulls) by changing data format. That might not be an option, but that does seem unnecessarily large.

Comment: I did the 1 off approach already, works, but like you said, it doesn't account for ongoing changes.  And yes, unfortunately, the target system is proprietary, and requires XML.

Answer (score 2):

My solution: add the attribute to the root node of the document like this:

```
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(...);

writer.WriteStartElement("root");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "p3", null, @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Then XmlSerializer doesn't have to write out the namespace at every nullable element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the nullable variables/elements were all String type. So, I simply performed a check and assigned them string.Empty in case of NULL. This way I got rid of the unnecessary nil and xmlns attributes (p3:nil="true" xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance)

```
// Example:

myNullableStringElement = varCarryingValue ?? string.Empty

// OR

myNullableStringElement = myNullableStringElement ?? string.Empty
```